# GWT ScrollPanel, bottom scrollbar is not scrollable

Tags: gwt

If I create a ScrollPanel like this:

```
public class BoardPanel extends ScrollPanel {

    public BoardPanel(Game game) {

        AbsolutePanel abs = new AbsolutePanel();

        setHeight("100px");
        setWidth("100px");
        setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
        abs.add(new Image(game.getMap().getImageUrl()));
        add(abs);  
    }
}
```

I got my picture with a scrollbar on the right, which is scrollable.
The bottom one is only shown, if I use `setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);`
My question is, how can I get the bottom one scrollable? It is just grey.

Comment: what is 'abs'.  If you aren't directly adding the image to the scroll panel it would be helpful to know what you are adding it to.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. It is an absolutePanel, because I need to draw on specific coordinates to realize animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class BoardPanel extends ScrollPanel {
AbsolutePanel abs = new AbsolutePanel();

private GameCtrl gameCtrl;

public BoardPanel(Game game) {
    setSize("100px", "100px");
    abs.add(new Image(game.getMap().getImageUrl()));
    abs.setPixelSize(768,576);
    add(abs);
    for (Player player : game.getPlayerList()) {
        drawRobot(player);
    }
}
```

I have fixed it, your hint was right, because he thinks that the whole image is displayed.
If I set the size of the AbsolutePanel, the bottom scrollbar appears and it looks like it should.

Answer (score 0):

If the bottom one is shown only if you use the setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true) then it most probably means the image is being fully displayed and there is nothing left to scroll

Comment: I think you are right, but as you can see, i used a size of 100x100 and the image is greater than that. It could be fully displayed on the screen, if the size were bigger than 100x100.